# dplyr collapse 'tail' rows into larger groups

Tags: r, dplyr

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(a = as.factor(1:20), b = c(50, 20, 13, rep(2, 10), rep(1, 7)))
```

How do I make dplyr look at this data frame `df` and collapse all these occurences of `2` into a single summed group, and collapse all the occurrences of `1` into a single summed group? And also keep the rest of the data frame.

Turn this:

```
# A tibble: 20 x 2
   a         b
   <fct> <dbl>
 1 1        50
 2 2        20
 3 3        13
 4 4         2
 5 5         2
 6 6         2
 7 7         2
 8 8         2
 9 9         2
10 10        2
11 11        2
12 12        2
13 13        2
14 14        1
15 15        1
16 16        1
17 17        1
18 18        1
19 19        1
20 20        1
```

into this:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
   a         b
   <fct> <dbl>
 1 1        50
 2 2        20
 3 3        13
 4 grp2     20
 5 grp1      7
```

*[Edit] - I fixed the example data. Sorry about that.*

Comment: To clarify, are `grp2` and `grp1` just characters or do they contain elements of `a` that correspond to `2` and `1`?

Comment: Thank you for correcting my example data. I forgot to do that originally. And thanks for your response, although I don't really need the `grp` elements to contain elements of `a`. But the response is illuminating and excellent.

Comment: @Julius Vainora it looks like your answer disappeared? Do you mind posting it? It was good and I didn't get a chance to copy paste it to my reference file. And I'm sure the rest of StackOverflow could find it useful. Thanks either way.

Comment: Sure, but as it answers a different question, I'll just leave it here: `df %>% group_by(b) %>% summarise(a = list(a)) %>% mutate(b = b * lengths(a))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We group by a manufactured `sortkey` to maintain sort order. We used the fact that `b` is in descending order in the input but if that is not the case in your actual data then replace `sortkey = -b` with the more general  `sortkey = data.table::rleid(b)`  or the longer `sortkey =  cumsum(coalesce(b != lag(b), FALSE))` .

We also convert `b` to the group names giving a new `a`.  It wasn't clear which groups are to be converted to grp... form.  Hard-coded 1 and 2?  Any group with more than one row?  Groups at the end with more than one row?  At any rate it would be easy enough to change the condition in the `if_else` once that were clarified.

Finally perform the summation and then remove the `sortkey`.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(sortkey = -b, a = paste0(if_else(b %in% 1:2, "grp", ""), b)) %>%
  summarize(b = sum(b)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-sortkey)
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  a         b
  <chr> <int>
1 50       50
2 20       20
3 13       13
4 grp2     20
5 grp1      7
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way. I have converted `a` from factor to character to make things easier. You can convert it back to factor if you want. Also your test data was a bit wrong.

```
df <- tibble(a = as.character(1:20), b = c(50, 20, 13, rep(2, 10), rep(1, 7)))

df %>% 
  mutate(
    a = case_when(
      b == 1 ~ "grp1",
      b == 2 ~ "grp2",
      TRUE ~ a
    )
  ) %>% 
  group_by(a) %>% 
  summarise(b = sum(b))

# A tibble: 5 x 2
  a         b
  <chr> <dbl>
1 1        50
2 2        20
3 3        13
4 grp1      7
5 grp2     20
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an approach which gives you the desired names for groups & where you don't need to think in advance how many cases like that you would need (e.g. it would create `grp3`, `grp4`, ... depending on the number in `b`).

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(
    grp = as.numeric(lag(df$b) != df$b),
    grp = cumsum(ifelse(is.na(grp), 0, grp))
  ) %>% group_by(grp) %>%
  mutate(
    a = ifelse(n() > 1, paste0("grp", b), a),
    b = sum(b)
  ) %>% ungroup() %>% distinct(a, b)
```

Output:

```
  a         b
  <chr> <dbl>
1 1        50
2 2        20
3 3        13
4 grp2     20
5 grp1      7
```

Note that the code could be also condensed but that leads to a certain lack of readability in my opinion:

```
df %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum(ifelse(is.na(as.numeric(lag(df$b) != df$b)), 0, as.numeric(lag(df$b) != df$b)))) %>%
  mutate(
    a = ifelse(n() > 1, paste0("grp", b), a),
    b = sum(b)
  ) %>% ungroup() %>% distinct(a, b)
```